# Complex Space Factorization

Tags: algorithm, r

I have posted a discussion on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649172/complex-space-factorization) regarding visualizing the complex space and effects of factorization methods on that space.  A quick link to the paper is available [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/298822749/Complex-Space-Factorization).  I have 3 routines in that paper, the first is the complex space generator.  It works, but it is very slow and would appreciate any suggestions on improvement.

Complex Space Generator:

```
Complex.Space.Generator <- function(N){
  min.real = ceiling(sqrt(N))
  segtop_x = ceiling(N/6)+1
  segtop_y = floor(N/6)-1
  plot(N,N,xlim=c((0),N/3), ylim =c((0),N/6),xlab="Real",ylab="Imaginary")
  segments(3,0,segtop_x,segtop_y)
  segments(segtop_x,segtop_y,N/3,0, lty = "dotted")

  for (i in 3:N/3){
    for (j in 0:N/3){
      i=as.integer(i)
      j=as.integer(j)
      if((i-j)>=3 && (i+j)<=(N/3) && (i-j)<=min.real)
        points(i,j, pch = 17,col = ifelse((i-j)*(i+j) < N,'blue',ifelse((i-j)*(i+j) == N,'green','red')))
    }
  }
}
```

The second routine is the simultaneous factorization method involving Fermat and trial division.  It is pretty fast, but I'm sure some improvements can be identified.

```
 Simultaneous.Complex.Factorization <- function(N){
 min.real = ceiling(sqrt(N))
 max.imaginary = min.real - 3
 divisor = min.real + max.imaginary ### 135degree yellow line
 ### Estimate of where complex space turns red
 min.imaginary = floor(mean(c((N/divisor),max.imaginary)))
 ### Corresponding real to above estimate
 max.real = divisor - min.imaginary
 j = 0L
 while (j>=0L ){
     if(
      sqrt(((min.real + j)^2) - N)%%1==0 |   ### Vertical Fermat

      sqrt(((max.imaginary - j)^2) + N)%%1==0 |    ### Horizontal Fermat

      (N/((min.real+j)-(max.imaginary-j)))%%1==0 |    ### Trial Division

      sqrt(((max.real - j)^2) - N)%%1==0 |    ### Vertical Fermat from estimate

      (N/((max.real-j)-(min.imaginary+j)))%%1==0    ### Trial Division from estimate
      ) {

return(as.matrix(c(iterations=j,
     mapped.real = (min.real+j)-(max.imaginary - j),
     Factor_v = if((sqrt((min.real+j)^2 - N))%%1==0) (min.real+j)-sqrt((min.real+j)^2 - N),
     Factor_h = if((sqrt((max.imaginary - j)^2 + N))%%1==0) (max.imaginary - j) + sqrt((max.imaginary - j)^2 + N),
     Factor_td = if((N/((min.real+j)-(max.imaginary-j)))%%1==0) (N/((min.real+j)-(max.imaginary-j))),
     Factor_v.2 = if((sqrt((max.real-j)^2 - N))%%1==0) (max.real-j)-sqrt((max.real-j)^2 - N),
     Factor_td.2 = if((N/((max.real-j)-(min.imaginary+j)))%%1==0) (N/((max.real-j)-(min.imaginary+j)))
     )))}

 j = j + 1L

  }
}
```

And finally I have the alternative method presented in the paper.  It is very slow compared to the above method even though it requires noticeably less iterations.

```
Viole.Factorization <- function(N){
 min.real = ceiling(sqrt(N))
 max.imgainary = (N-9)/6
 iterated.average = 0L

 for (i in 2:log2(max.imgainary)){
      iterated.average[1] = mean(c(min.real,N))
      iterated.average[i] = mean(c(iterated.average[i-1],N))
      }

 descending.iterations = floor(iterated.average)
 ascending.iterations = ceiling(iterated.average)
 print(iterated.average)
 j = 0L

 while(j>=0L){
      for(i in 1:length(iterated.average)){
      if( (descending.iterations[i]-j > descending.iterations[i-1] | ascending.iterations[i]+j < ascending.iterations[i+1]) &&
      GCD(descending.iterations[i]-j,N)>1 && GCD(descending.iterations[i]-j,N)<N |
      GCD(ascending.iterations[i]+j,N)>1 && GCD(ascending.iterations[i]+j,N)<N
      ){

 return(c("Factor"=GCD(descending.iterations[i]-j,N),"Factor"=GCD(ascending.iterations[i]+j,N),"Iterated.Average.Level"=i,"Iterations"=j))}
      }
 j = j + 1L
 }
}
```

I look forward to any insights regarding the routines.  If you have any suggestions or questions on the content of the paper then please comment on the [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649172/complex-space-factorization) discussion.